# How do you configure a dynamic block for a customer segment in M2C?

Tags: magento2.3, cms, magento2-enterprise, dynamic-blocks

Using Magento Commerce (nee EE) 2.3.1, how do you configure a Dynamic Block to render for a specific customer segment?

The stock Magento documentation:

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/cms/dynamic-blocks.html

does not give you much to work with if it's *not* working.

I have a Customer Segment set up for any customer that has placed an order (which has 1 customer record - using the sample data). I have a Cart Rule for 20% off, I want to show a Dynamic Block to that customer segment to promote the Cart Rule.

I have the Dynamic Block set up, and dropped into a CMS page:
[image]

[image: screenshots]

but when I log in as the customer in the customer segment, no promo Dynamic Block appears on the CMS page.

Customer segment, showing the 1 customer in the segment I'm logging in as:

[image]

I've reindexed and cleared the cache.

Comment: Do You see block when You add to customer segment for visitors?

Comment: @BartZalas - I removed the segment restriction, and the block was visible.

Comment: So something with your customer segment settings, can you share screen shot?

Comment: @BartZalas - added a screenshot of the segment.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what was going on here, but changing the customer segment conditions from `greater than 1` to `equals or greater than 1`, saving, then resetting to `greater than 1` fixed the issue, even though the customer was included in the segment the first time.